# Adding note in Django Admin site's TubularInline

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Currently my django admin site's setup looks like

```
Topic

  submit_date: 2018/09/25
  submit_user: blah

Topic-category1

  sub-topic    field1    field2
---------------------------------
  bleh         bleh1     bleh2
  mlem         mlem1     mlem2

Topic-category2

  something    something1    something2
---------------------------------------
  asd          asd1          asd2
  asd2         asd2-1        asd2-2
```

I want to add a note section in between `Topic-category1` and the table, so it looks like

```
Topic-category1

<this is where the note goes, functions like description>

  sub-topic    field1    field2
---------------------------------
  bleh         bleh1     bleh2
  mlem         mlem1     mlem2
```

Is there a way for django admin to do it? I'm not using any of the custom form. Only using `ModelAdmin` and modify variables here and there

Answer (score 0):

Okay turns out I can't do it without having a custom form for Django Admin.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets

I can add description using `fieldsets`, but it doesn't apply to TabularInline as it cannot be rendered.